# Changing Date Format of Twitter Api DATA in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, twitter, datetime-format

i want to change date format of twitter api data it like this :

Fri Sep 11 08:31:48 +0000 2009

i want to convert it into format like this :

YYYY-DD-MM 00:00:00

How do i convert this in sql server 2012

Comment: By 00:00:00 do you mean you want to drop the time?

Comment: Well, here are both. The SET is important. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/3617

Comment: But there is a problem with this when i convert with this code the column is converted in to date format but when i convert it with (100,103,111,etc) it does not convert it in given format . it gives the same format

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late, but this is what worked for me

```
    alter table Test
add [date2] as (

CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(created_at,9,2)+'/'
  + CASE SUBSTRING(created_at,5,3)
    WHEN 'Jan' then '01/'
    WHEN 'Feb' then '02/'
    WHEN 'Mar' then '03/'
    WHEN 'Apr' then '04/'
    WHEN 'May' then '05/'
    WHEN 'Jun' then '06/'
    WHEN 'Jul' then '07/'
    WHEN 'Aug' then '08/'
    WHEN 'Sep' then '09/'
    WHEN 'Oct' then '10/'
    WHEN 'Nov' then '11/'
    WHEN 'Dec' then '12/'
  else '' end
  +RIGHT(created_at,4) + ' '
  + SUBSTRING(created_at,12,8), 105)

)
PERSISTED;
```